# Flutter -- escape special character in a string

Tags: flutter

I have a string in Flutter that I would like to escape the single quote.

e.g 'associate's degree' should be 'associates\s degree'.

Is there a build-in flutter/dart function to do this operation.

Thanks

Comment: Which result do you want? `associates\s degree` or `associates's degree`? Did you mean replace `'` or escape `'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the context. You could obviously use:

```
print('blu\'bb'.replaceAll("'", "\\'"));
```

But typically you escape for a specific reason, like if you want to use it in a JSON string (use `dart:convert`) or because you want to use it in a url (use `Uri` class), etc.